# DRF: Using Serializer field 'fields'

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to use a serializer having the field `fields`:

```
class MySerializer(Serializer):
    fields = CharField(required=True)
```

But `Serializer` class already has a method named `fields`.
So there is ambiguity in using this attribute of the instance and class, which can lead to errors and mess up with static analyzers:

```
>>> a = MySerializer()
>>> a.fields
{'fields': CharField(required=True)}

>>> MySerializer.fields
<django.utils.functional.cached_property object at 0x543543215670>
```

So, I wonder, is there the way to declare a serializer class with an alias like:

```
class MySerializer(Serializer):
    fields_ = CharField(required=True, alias='fields')
```

The important part is to make it able to parse input data with the alias `fields`:

```
>>> a = MySerializer(data={'fields': 'some text'})
>>> a.is_valid()
True

>>> a.validated_data
OrderedDict([('fields', 'some text')])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using ModelSerializer, it should work.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Your Model Class Name
        fields = ('fields',)
        # or use fields = '__all__'
```

Documentation: [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: I'm not using any Model under the hood. It's definitely not my case.